# How to improve the performance for System.currentTimeMillis();?

Tags: java, performance, time, clock

The  `System.currentTimeMillis();` is system method in Java.
If invoke this method serially, it seems that no performance issues.
But if you keep invoking this method concurrently, the performance issue will occurred explicitly. As the native method dependent with OS clock_source. But how to improve it performance in Java. Refresh time milli policy with fixed rate is not usable.

Examples like below:

```
int parallism = 32;

for(int i=0;i< parallism ;i++){
    new Thread(() -> {
        for(;;){

            // Focus here, how can i measure the logic efficiently
            long begin = System.currentTimeMillis();
            
            // Here may be the logic: 
            // Define empty block here means 0ms elapsed

            long elapsed = (System.currentTimeMillis() - begin);
            if(elapsed >= 5){
                System.err.println("Elapsed: "+elapsed+" ms.");
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

Thread.sleep(Integer.MAX_VALUE); // Just avoid process exit
```

Comment: instantiating 32 Threads will have more of a hit.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The provided code is not how you would benchmark how much time `currentTimeMillis` actually takes.  There's no way to make it faster. Edit the question with what you're actually trying to do here. Why did it come up? There is no general 'just use this instead' answer, but for a specific use case, there might be a specific answer.

Comment: I just wanna to measure the elapsed time of the code that define in the Thread.run().

Comment: And what are you getting?

Comment: O_o     I just wanna getting the elapsed time (efficiently) which is now_time minus previous_time. So got it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
System.nanoTime() instead of System.currentTimeMills();
```

Comment: Better how? What's your source?

Comment: And why is this a new answer?